# simple submit form using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a simple form app, where there will be a textarea input and a submit button. Where, if I type something in the textarea and then click submit, the text that I just typed will show under the button inside a  tag. When im doing this without Redux, it works fine, even after when I use Redux partly meaning when I manage only one state (input field state) using Redux it works great. But when i make two reducers, and two dispatches then problem happens. Here are my codes.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Provider from 'react-redux/es/components/Provider';
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware,
    combineReducers,
} from 'redux';
import { getInput, getOutput } from './reducer';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    getInput,
    getOutput,
});
const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(logger)
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    changeInput,
    postOutput,
} from './action';
import {
    Form,
    Button,
    Container,
} from 'react-bootstrap';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        input: state.getInput.input,
        output: state.getOutput.output,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleInput: (event) =>
            dispatch(changeInput(event.target.value)),
        handleClick: (props) =>
            dispatch(postOutput(props.output)),
    };
};

class App extends Component {
    // constructor() {
    //  super();
    //  this.state = {
    //      output: '',
    //  };
    // }

    // handleInput = (event) => {
    //  this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
    // };

    // handleClick = () => {
    //  this.setState({
    //      output: this.props.input,
    //  });
    // };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Container>
                    {' '}
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId='exampleForm.ControlTextarea1'>
                            <div>
                                <div
                                    style={{
                                        display: 'flex',
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                        marginTop: '20px',
                                        marginBottom: '10px',
                                    }}>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        as='textarea'
                                        rows={5}
                                        placeholder='enter something here'
                                        onChange={this.props.handleInput}
                                        style={{ width: '500px' }}
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div
                                    style={{
                                        display: 'flex',
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                    }}>
                                    <Button
                                        variant='primary'
                                        onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
                                        Submit
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Container>
                <div
                    style={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                    }}>
                    <h1 value={this.props.input}>
                        {this.props.output}
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

action.js

```
import {
    CHANGE_INPUT_FIELD,
    POST_OUTPUT,
} from './constant';

export const changeInput = (text) => ({
    type: CHANGE_INPUT_FIELD,
    payload: text,
});

export const postOutput = (text) => ({
    type: POST_OUTPUT,
    payload: text,
});
```

reducer.js

```
import {
    CHANGE_INPUT_FIELD,
    POST_OUTPUT,
} from './constant';

const initialStateInput = {
    input: '',
};

const initialStateOutput = {
    output: '',
};

export const getInput = (
    state = initialStateInput,
    action = {}
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_INPUT_FIELD:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                input: action.payload,
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const getOutput = (
    state = initialStateOutput,
    action = {}
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case POST_OUTPUT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                output: action.payload,
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

constant.js

```
export const CHANGE_INPUT_FIELD =
    'CHANGE_INPUT_FIELD';

export const POST_OUTPUT = 'POST_OUTPUT';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `changeInput` action must be handled inside the component there is no reason to dispatch an action and handle it with reducer because reducer is for managing shared states.
2. Can you specify what is the "problem"?

Comment: when i click submit, doesnt show anything. I know its silly to put handleClick in dispatch. I was just practicing redux, its just for practice purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is not with actions, you cannot see the value because the value is set to `undefined`
2. In App.js you have to pass the correct value
   `onClick={this.props.handleClick}>` must change as `onClick={this.props.handleClick(this.props)}>` otherwise props will be equal to event object in the line `handleClick: (props) => dispatch(postOutput(props.output))`
3. Still you won't see the value in UI because the output value is set to `''` because you are not setting the input value to the output value in reducer.
4. My suggestion there must be another action that fires when submit button is clicked and sets the current input value to the input, then fire `getOutput`

Comment: Can you write the code for me so i can get a better picture, this would help me a lot as i am just learning 